# Make sub nav slidedown and slideup toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Create a navigation with a sub-nav or child page.
- When the user clicks on about, I want the about to toggle the Bob li.
- It should slide down and slide up when clicked on and off of about.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grab").click(function() {
    $(".sub-nav").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li id="#grab">About
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>Bob</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>Faqs</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<li id="#grab">` remove `#` from `id`

Comment: remove **#** from id so it should be <li id="grab">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is wrong you have a hashtag before grab `id="#grab"` it should be `id="grab"` by default the li contain "Bob" will be show to resolve this issue, add `display:none;` to the ul either through a class or inline

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grab").click(function() {
    $(".sub-nav").stop().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul class="nav">
  <li id="grab">About
   <ul style="display:none" class="sub-nav">
    <li >Bob</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 <li>Contact</li>
 <li>Faqs</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#` is used to reference id, in your tag you're seting the id as `#grab`, and in your jquery you're setting the [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event to the class `grab`.
Then you'll need to change your `<li>` id to `grab`:

```
<li id="grab">
```

---

You can add `display: none` to your `<ul>`. In that way, when the page load, the `sub-nav` starts hidden:

You can set this on the tag:

```
<ul class="sub-nav" style="display: none;">
```

Or in your css:

```
.sub-nav{
  display: none;
}
```